# Get substring of field using EF and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, t-sql

I want to get the first line from a text field in a SQL Server table via EF.  I have this LINQ query to return up to the first CRLF or all text if there is no CRLF, but it doesn't seem to generate the most efficient TSQL.

```
from f in context.MyTable
select f.TextField.Substring(0, f.TextField.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) > 0 ?
                                f.TextField.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) :
                                f.TextField.Length)
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: What makes you think the generated SQL is not efficient? And what SQL does it generate?

Comment: Actually now that I've analysed the SQL properly it is maybe not so bad - I initially saw the "0+1" and the CASE statement and freaked. Here it is    `SUBSTRING([Extent1].[ErrorMessage], 0 + 1, CASE WHEN ((( CAST(CHARINDEX(@p__linq__1, [Extent1].[ErrorMessage]) AS int)) - 1) > 0) THEN ( CAST(CHARINDEX(@p__linq__2, [Extent1].[ErrorMessage]) AS int)) - 1 ELSE  CAST(LEN([Extent1].[ErrorMessage]) AS int) END) AS [C1]`

Answer (score 0):

If you think the generated `SQL` is not efficient, you can also use the Database. Sql Query method. Using this you can use your raw query. Unless you want to use `LINQ`, it should be a decent way as well.

```
context.Table.SqlQuery("SELECT --- FROM dbo.Table").ToList();
```

Although, if you could share the generated sql, then it would be more helpful.